# Rewriting "HackerType" with Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I was directed to the website Hackertyper.com - and it intrigued me very much. So I decided that, using Java, I would attempt to re-write it. I stumbled on some issues while I did it.

Currently, so far from my intro Java course, I only learned how to use the Scanner class, so at the moment, my "code" only takes an input after pressing the "Enter" key. At the same time, upon pressing enter, the entire String gets printed out.

My questions are:

1. Are there any libraries in which it would take an input (any key on the keyboard, in this case) and do something without pressing "Enter", and.
2. What do I need to do in order to take an input, stop the piece of code, wait for the next input, before executing the next loop?

So far below is the very poorly written code of what I have.

```
String paragraph = "hellothere";

        Scanner newInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = newInput.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < paragraph.length(); i++){
            if(input.equals("2")){
                System.out.print(paragraph.charAt(i));
                input = newInput.nextLine(); // call input again after executed the loop
            }
        }
```

After I solve these issues I think I will dabble with IO and let Java call a text file in which inside would have pieces of code, which onKeyPress would type out the i-th index.

Thanks!

Comment: You need at least two `Thread`s, one to read and one to write.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by "at least two threads"?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean [Hacker Typer](http://hackertyper.com), not hacker type?

1) I think what you need is a [key listener event](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

2) You could write a method that is called when the key event fires. The method would then return a piece of text. <strike>You store the text in an array, so it always returns the next piece of code.</strike>
<strike>To create the array from string you can use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)</strike>
**edit:** i just saw that it always puts two characters, not the next word.

Comment: Yes, I meant Hacker Typer. Thanks for the help! I am currently trying to implement it so the program reads from a text file with some random pieces of code and prints out the i-th char on key presses.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you used the `SWT` toolkit.

For a functional example, run my code below. You only need to add the SWT dependencies.

Writing into the console is silly. This is much cooler:

```
public class Waffles
{
    // Keeps track of how many times any key is pressed
    private static int keyCounter = 0;

    // Used to continuously append characters from the input string
    private final StringBuilder builder;

    // This can be read from a file, or whatever
    private final String GIBBERISH;

    public static void main(final String[] args) 
    {
            new Waffles();
    }

    private Waffles() 
    {
            builder = new StringBuilder();

            // Put your dummy code here (extract from a file)
            GIBBERISH = " I freaking love waffles!";

            // Loop the SWT Display
            init();
    }

    private void init() 
    {
            final Display display = new Display();
            final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
            shell.setText("HackerTyper");
            shell.setSize(500, 500);
            shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

            // Here we create the text area
            createWidget(shell);

            shell.open();
            while (!shell.isDisposed()) 
            {
                  if (!display.readAndDispatch()) 
                        display.sleep();
            }
            display.dispose();
    }

    private void createWidget(final Composite parent)
    {
            // Wrap it for multi line text, and set it to read only, so we can't modify 
            // the text 'manually'
            final Text textArea = new Text(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP | SWT.READ_ONLY);
            textArea.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

            // Yay colours! 
            textArea.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
            textArea.setForeground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));

            // This is what was recommended by the other two answers
            textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() 
            {

                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent arg0) 
                    {
                           // *magic*
                           textArea.setText( getGibberish() );
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent arg0) 
                    {

                    }

            });
    }

    private String getGibberish()
    {
            if (keyCounter > GIBBERISH.length() - 1)
                    keyCounter = 0; // Careful not to go out of string bounds

            // Continuously append it, then pass the whole text to the textArea
            builder.append( GIBBERISH.charAt(keyCounter++) );
            return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

FEEL like a hacker.
BE like a hacker. HUZZZAAA! 
I'm really tired.

Comment: If this is what I think it is - you took my "idea" and shot it into the moon. Good job dude. Man, I wish I could code like a pro.

Comment: http://oi42.tinypic.com/2euh4xv.jpg Here's a screenshot of what it does. If you have any questions on the code, do not hesitate to ask. Hope I helped you in some way.

Comment: I just randomly came across this question...how would we format the text like actual code? That would be difficult, but it seems like a fun thing to think about...Any ideas?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia You paste some actual code in the `GIBBERISH` constant. :-) Or you can even read it from a file, instead of using a constant.

Comment: HackerTyper probably has a file in a database...maybe it just loops through the file when you reach the end...

Answer (score 0):

There is an interface called KeyListener but this only works with [swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) classes, and based on you're code this a console application. You could use [JNativehook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) which allows you to use swing events in a console application. You should learn basic swing events before using this though.